# AngularJS $watch function calling repeatedly - How to prevent it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a function call I need to check for a change in a array element.
If any change occurs I need the function to continue or else to stop the execution.

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.watchCollection('checkedCountry',function(newval,oldval) {
         if (newval!==oldval) {
               console.log("dothings");  // this is executing multiple times. 
         } 
    })
}
```

But for a single call of myFunction am getting output of multiple times dothings.

I need it to work only once for a function call and if the collection changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you have shared, the number of watches that would be setup is directly proportional to the number of times the function `myFunction` is called. Therefore, everytime you call `myFunction` a new watch is setup. An change to the collection hence will trigger all the watches.

Normally watches are setup in some type of initialization function that is called only once.

I would suggest move your watch setup outside the `myFunction` call.

Comment: If I move the watch outside my function. Is there a way to check whether the collection have any changes on the call of my function.

Comment: No sure of your scenario, but your watch code should have the method code? Mostly the scenario i have seen w.r.t watch is that we want to trigger something on collection change.

Comment: My problem in when the function is called .. then I have to check whether  any  change in my collection.

Comment: @Explore-X you need to set true value after a function..that will deep watch on your collection `$scope.watchCollection('checkedCountry',function(newval,oldval){
         if(newval!==oldval){
               console.log("dothings");  // this is executing multiple times. 
         } 
    },true)`

Comment: The way to go about it would be then inside the watch callback set some variable like `changed=true` and in the function `myFunction` check the value of `changed` and if true, do you operation and then reset it back to `false`.